# Java Track 1 data pattern unclosed group error

Tags: java, regex

I have this pattern that matches Bank card Track 1 data:

```
private static final Pattern track1FormatBPattern = Pattern
        .compile("(%?([A-Z])([0-9]{1,19})\\^([^\\^]{2,26})\\^([0-9]{4}|\\^)([0-9]{3}|\\^)?([^\\?]+)?\\??)[\t\n\r ]{0,2}.*");
```

However Android Studio states that there is a unclosed group. As I see it all groups are closed. What need to be added/removed in order the pattern to compile cleanly (btw, it works, just the AS marks it as an error).

Comment: Looks, fine to me. You could probably remove some backslashes inside your character classes. `"(%?([A-Z])([0-9]{1,19})\\^([^^]{2,26})\\^([0-9]{4}|\\^)([0-9]{3}|\\^)?([^?]+)?\\??)[\\t\\n\\r ]{0,2}.*"`  But over-escaping is usually not a bad thing here.

Comment: @zlakad Regex is probably unappealing because it's generally hard to read. Most people don't utilize white-space mode, and many languages don't even support it. A regex can probably be replaced by a well-designed data structure. If there's a good parser for the data type, then that's probably better than coming up with a regex. But if you know regex and have a good regex engine, regex can be the most lightweight tool for reformatting data quickly and efficiently, instead of relying on a bad or nonexistent parser. You also start to learn strategies for avoiding efficiency and behavior pitfalls.

Comment: I am using intellij idea, on which AS is based and it shows no error for me.

Comment: @gagansingh Yep, I have tested it in Idea too. Probably Google made some "enhancements" in AS and introduced a bug...

Comment: Did you try wp78de's suggestion? It might fix the issue as the ``\t``, ``\n`` and ``\r`` are properly escaped.

Comment: They don't need to be escaped. The problem was that the regex is working properly just the Intellij IDEA is showing an error...